# Имплементация Map

Tags: java, map

Вопрос с собеседования. Больше данных нет. Что должен вернуть `Action.f3()`? Предложите другую имплементацию Map с таким же поведением.
У меня почему-то метод вернул `null`.

**Action.class**

```
public class Action {

    public static Object f3() {
        Map map = new HashMap(20);
        map.put("1", "One");
        map.put("2", "Two");
        map.put("3", "Three");
        Map myMap = new MyMap(map);
        return myMap.get("1");
    }
}
```

**MyMap.class**

```
class MyMap implements Map {

    private Map anotherMap;

    public MyMap(Map anotherMap) {
        this.anotherMap = anotherMap;
    }

    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        // .....
    }

    public Object get(Object key) {
        Iterator it = anotherMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry e = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            if (key.equals(e.getValue())) {
                return e.getKey();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public int size() {
        //....
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: ну по логике, ожидаемое поведение - вернуть `One`. Мы создаём свою реализацию `myMap` передав в конструктор другой `Map` вроде как нужно скопировать все поля. А вопрос в чём? И честно говоря метод `get` какой-то _странный_ зачем в `map` брать элемент за `O(n)` если любой `map` не хуже `O(log N)` это делает...

Comment: nullу вас т.к Вы nullи возвращаете -> return null; иными словами у вас все работает

Comment: вы точно не перепутали в методе `get` где ключ а где значение используется?

Comment: Скопировано с задания один в один. В чем подвох вопроса пока не уяснил, пытаюсь разобраться.

Comment: Задача видимо чисто на проверку вашей внимательности

Answer (score 4):

```
Map.Entry e = (Map.Entry) it.next();
if (key.equals(e.getValue()))
    ^^^ Вы сравниваете ключ с значением.
{
    return e.getKey();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Все верно, приведенный код вернет `null`.
Посмотрите внимательнее в имплементацию метода `get` в `MyMap`, а точнее на условие в `if`. Там у Вас сравнивается аргумент, переданный в `get`, со **значением** `entry`( Вы сравниваете `"1"` c `"One"`, `"Two"`, `"Three"`).  Естественно совпадений нет, и, пройдя циклом по всем `entry`, попадает на `return null`.